# Application as part of Android Built

Tags: android, android-build

I had built a application using the Android SDK. Now I would like to package this application as part of the Android build. So that when I port Android into my device, it will appear in the Application menu.

I tried, copying the apk file into the package folder, and include it in the make file. Doesn't work.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

if you have android source tree, you can put your project under packages/apps.
And modify ./build/target/product/generic.mk.